# Get d3 to show correct dates based on timestamp

Tags: javascript, php, datetime, d3.js

I'm creating a graph with d3 with data from the database, but don't get the date to show properly, instead it only shows 01/17/1970.

I get the date from database in this format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

and convert it to a timestamp with:

```
strtotime($t)
```

this results in timestamps like:

```
1417215600, 1417302000, 1417388400
```

But the chart does only show above mentioned unix second null.

And this is how the x-Axis is formated:

```
 chart.xAxis
           .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d)) });
```

I live in Italy and the default timezone in my application is CET, so I tried to set

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

but with no success.

Can someone advice?

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by adding .000 to every timestamp, javascript wants 13 character timestamps instead of php's 10 character timestamp:

```
strtotime($t).'000'
```

returns the correct output for my chart

Comment: It's not D3 that wants 13 character timestamps, but JavaScript which uses **milliseconds** for dates.

Comment: @michael: fix that in your answer, because currently your answer is wrong, and you are teaching wrong belief.